# Empty mesh after "Mesh from Curve" (Alt+C)

Tags: mesh

**Solution**

Thanks to moonboots for pointing out my mistake. I forgot to fill the curve before converting it to a mesh. You can see the solution in the screenshot below:

[image]

**Problem**

I have created a **(closed) bezier curve**. After that I changed the mode from **"Edit Mode"** to **"Object Mode"**. Finally, I selected the whole curve and hit **"Alt+C"** to **convert it to a mesh**.

However, all of a sudden now it does create a mesh but it seems to be **empty**. You can see the **background grid through the mesh** because there does not seem to be the default blueish grey color on it.

I have successfully used this method before to convert a curve into a mesh and I can't find what I have done wrong/ different now.

I have already used Google to find a solution but looking for the term **"Empty mesh after mesh from curve"** has not given me any results.
And looking for tutorials for creating a mesh from a bezier always give me the same error.

There is also a screenshot attached. I can also upload the project file to Dropbox if wanted.

As you can see the selected object is a mesh since it has the triangle icon.

[image]

Thanks for any answers. I have already spent quite some time to find a solution but nothing helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: you say that you have successfully used this technique before, but wasn't your bezier curve already full, i.e. in properties > Data > Shape > 2D with Fill = Back for example

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that was the problem. This time I did not fill the bezier so the mesh remained empty.

Comment: If an answer was indeed what helped you, remember to mark it as the correct one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fill your bezier curve before converting it to mesh: Select your curve then go in *Properties* > *Data* > *Shape* > *2D* with *Fill* = *Back*, for example

Comment: This is the right answer, I also took a screenshot to visualize it. For those who have the same problem: You can see the **screenshot on the top of my question**. Thanks for helping me (and maybe others) out.